# C/C++ build tools dependency managment

Tags: c++

Which are the C/C++ build tools that solves transitive dependencies and make it possible to draw a dependency graph ?

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any build tool to easily "solve" all the transitive dependencies. But to output a dependency graph...
[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) maybe?
Or you can use the -M and -H options for the GCC compiler to ouput the dependency list/tree.